# How can I add details to goals in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

I have been using goals in Google Calendar for quite sometime now. They are very handy and easy to use. Just create a goal you want to accomplish, set preferred time and frequency and you are all set.

However, there are some extra things that i want to do with Goals in Google calendar that would make the experience much more delightful. I want to add details to goals.

For instance, I have a goal `workout`. Now, Let's assume that i have set this goal for 1hr every morning. Now, one day i decide that i will not do pushups tomorrow. To accomplish this, I want to add details to the `workout` goal for tomorrow. However, I cannot do that!

Is there a way to do that in Google Calendar? If not, is there an external application that might do it for me and that syncs with Google Calendar?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Google Calendar Goals don't support any fields to customize with text.

But since everything in Google Calendar, including Goals and To-dos, is just an event, you still can customize using a different approach. First let's see what a Google Calendar "Goal" is, it's a simplified event that is named "Workout" and it usually repeats some time during the week. If you look at your Work out event in the mobile apps, you'll notice it has the dumbbell image as the header image and the name will be "Workout", it's getting the image because of the name, nothing special happens besides the naming. The repetition is an easy to use feature when setting up the goal but it's entirely possible when creating a regular Google Calendar event as well.

TL;DR to achieve what you're asking for, you should create your "Workout" goals as a regular event and then you'll be able to edit the description and other details. You'll still see the header image being dumbbells as long as you name it "Workout". And repetition is possible, just set it up when creating a regular calendar event.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking the same. I will use events instead of creating google goals. +1

Comment: is there a way to get information of Google Goal if it is done or not yet done? with Python API or any other API?